# Max Storage Capacity SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, storage, storage-quota

We have a limit of 7.74TB with an E5 subscription. Does anyone know the limit Microsoft will give a SharePoint Online instance? We are wanting to store a lot of data, like > 50TB.

What will MS sell you? Do they go up to Petabytes if you want to pay for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"You can purchase an unlimited amount of additional SharePoint Online storage."

See:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/servicedescriptions/sharepoint-online-service-description/sharepoint-online-limits

- Storage for site collections

  - Up to 25 TB per site collection or group
- Site collections per organization

  - 500,000

Comment: thanks, do you know how much? I can't find a price anywhere except $0.2 / GB

Comment: Sorry I don't. That's probably a "ask Microsoft" kind of thing. :-)